# why teaser from Tilemill won't show up on mapbox.js?

Tags: mapbox, tilemill

I used Tilemill to style my data, added teaser for points, then save then uploaded the project at data on mapbox.com then referred to those data on my [website](http://lucamoiana.github.io/mapboxtest.html) using "[Layers](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/layers/)" on mapbox.js examples why are my tooltips not showing up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still need to add your gridLayer and gridControl to your addLayer function. [Example](http://bl.ocks.org/geografa/b9a58b5b53ea84bc6517).